# Can't scrape a link connected to some download button from a page using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to download a csv file from a ***[webpage](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL)*** using requests module. The idea is to parse the link connected to [download button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqi2H.jpg) so that I can use the link to download the csv file. The link that I'm trying to grab is a dynamic one but I've noticed so far that there is always some way to find that. However, I just couldn't make it possible.

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/history?p=AAPL"

r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
file_link = soup.select_one("a[href='/finance/download/']").get("href")
print(file_link)
```

With the above attempt, the script throws `AttributeError:` as it could not find the link in that site.

> How can I fetch the downloadlink from that page using requests?

Comment: Use selenium way to download the file

Comment: Thanks for our suggestion @Vin but I'm not willing to use selenium. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the link to download the CSV is constructed dynamically via JavaScript. But you can construct similar link using Python:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime


csv_link = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{quote}?period1={from_}&period2={to_}&interval=1d&events=history'

quote = 'AAPL'
from_ = datetime(2019,9,27,0,0).strftime('%s')
to_ = datetime(2020,9,27,23,59).strftime('%s')

print(requests.get(csv_link.format(quote=quote, from_=from_, to_=to_)).text)
```

Prints:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2019-09-27,220.539993,220.960007,217.279999,218.820007,216.670242,25352000
2019-09-30,220.899994,224.580002,220.789993,223.970001,221.769623,25977400
2019-10-01,225.070007,228.220001,224.199997,224.589996,222.383545,34805800
2019-10-02,223.059998,223.580002,217.929993,218.960007,216.808853,34612300
2019-10-03,218.429993,220.960007,215.130005,220.820007,218.650574,28606500
2019-10-04,225.639999,227.490005,223.889999,227.009995,224.779770,34619700
2019-10-07,226.270004,229.929993,225.839996,227.059998,224.829269,30576500
2019-10-08,225.820007,228.059998,224.330002,224.399994,222.195404,27955000
2019-10-09,227.029999,227.789993,225.639999,227.029999,224.799576,18692600
2019-10-10,227.929993,230.440002,227.300003,230.089996,227.829498,28253400
2019-10-11,232.949997,237.639999,232.309998,236.210007,233.889374,41698900
2019-10-14,234.899994,238.130005,234.669998,235.869995,233.552719,24106900
2019-10-15,236.389999,237.649994,234.880005,235.320007,233.008133,21840000
2019-10-16,233.369995,235.240005,233.199997,234.369995,232.067444,18475800
2019-10-17,235.089996,236.149994,233.520004,235.279999,232.968521,16896300
2019-10-18,234.589996,237.580002,234.289993,236.410004,234.087433,24358400
2019-10-21,237.520004,240.990005,237.320007,240.509995,238.147125,21811800
2019-10-22,241.160004,242.199997,239.619995,239.960007,237.602539,20573400
2019-10-23,242.100006,243.240005,241.220001,243.179993,240.790909,18957200

...and so on.
```

---

EDIT:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime


csv_link = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{quote}?period1={from_}&period2={to_}&interval=1d&events=history'

quote = 'AAPL'
from_ = str(datetime.timestamp(datetime(2019,9,27,0,0))).split('.')[0]
to_ = str(datetime.timestamp(datetime(2020,9,27,23,59))).split('.')[0]

print(requests.get(csv_link.format(quote=quote, from_=from_, to_=to_)).text)
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the kind of answer  I was looking for. I'm facing a little trouble executing the script, though. While executing the script, I get this error `from_ = datetime(2019,9,27,0,0).strftime('%s')
ValueError: Invalid format string` Btw, I'm using `python 3.7.0`.

Comment: @MITHU See my edit. Basically, you need to `datetime` to UNIX timestamp.

Comment: Yep, I noticed. Thanks a lot.